# NodeWebkit win.title don't refresh title windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I need change title of my app :

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.title='My new title'; // Don't refresh title

// Force reflesh
win.resizeBy(-1, 0);
win.resizeBy(1, 0);
```

Any best soluce ?
Tested on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in onLoad or any script you're using

```
document.title = 'Your new title';
```